# webpack separate build files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx

I have a nested directory structure with jsx modules, like
app/js/header/index.jsx
app/js/task/runner.jsx
and so on

is it possible to have webpack transpile each one of them and output the result in the same directory as the jsx file?

Regards

Comment: There are dozens of tutorials on this easily findable with a quick Google search. Can you make your question more specific? What have you tried?

Comment: You think I just had a question and headed straight away here without first searching? Since there are a lot of relevant sources, would you mind sharing some instead of downvoting and criticizing?

Comment: I'm a big fan of the [react-production-starter](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/react-production-starter) repo, which stays up-to-date with the latest and greatest. Check out how they do their Webpack. It's advanced, but along with doing any Webpack tutorial it should start to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to put resulting module next to each source module. It seems that you can achieve this with a plugin:

```
var fs = require('fs');
function MyPlugin() {}

MyPlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
  compiler.plugin('emit', function(compilation, callback) {

    compilation.modules.forEach(m => {
      if (/filename/.test(m.resource)) { // test for filename to exclude node_modules
        fs.writeFileSync(m.resource + '.transpiled', m._source._value);
      }
    });

    callback();
  });
};
```

and in the webpack config:

```
{
...
plugins: [ MyPlugin() ],
...
}
```

Is it what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the help. This can point me to the direction I need. Regards